# Java: Need help pointing out NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Need help pointing out which one causes the NullPointerException. I've tried everything from what I understand but still no luck.

```
import com.threed.jpct.Object3D;

public class HelloShader extends Activity implements OnScaleGestureListener {

    private float ind = 0;
    private boolean doLoop = true;
    private Ticker ticker = new Ticker(15);
    private Object3D snork = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startLoop();    //NullPointerException according to LogCat
    }

    public void initialize(){
        snork = Loader.loadMD2(res.openRawResource(R.raw.image), 0.5f);
        snork.translate(0, 50, 0);
        Texture snorkTexture = new Texture(res.openRawResource(R.raw.imagetexture));
        tm.addTexture("snorkText", snorkTexture);
        snork.setTexture("snorkText");
    }

    public void startLoop(){

        long ticks = 0;

        while (doLoop) {

            ticks = ticker.getTicks();
            if (ticks > 0) {

                animate(ticks); //NullPointerException according to LogCat
            }
        }
    }

    private void animate(long ticks) {
        if (ticks > 0) {
            float ft = (float) ticks;
            ind += 0.02f * ft;
            if (ind > 1) {
                ind -= 1;
            }
            snork.animate(ind, 2);  //NullPointerException according to LogCat

        }
    }

    private static class Ticker {

        private int rate;
        private long s2;

        public static long getTime() {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public Ticker(int tickrateMS) {
            rate = tickrateMS;
            s2 = Ticker.getTime();
        }

        public int getTicks() {
            long i = Ticker.getTime();
            if (i - s2 > rate) {
                int ticks = (int) ((i - s2) / (long) rate);
                s2 += (long) rate * ticks;
                return ticks;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This is just part of the code which returns error, the whole code is very long so I didn't post them all because the other parts are irrelevant to the error. I've put the comment for the line that returns NullPointerException. Thank you in advance =) Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: The stacktrace should tell you what line it occurs on? You can also add some system.out.println messages to print out if various variables are null just before. If you're in an ide, you can step through using the debugger to see whats null

Comment: you never call initialize() method. it will initiate  snork = Loader.loadMD2(res.openRawResource(R.raw.image), 0.5f); snork object.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't called `initialize` before calling `animate`, which is called during `onCreate`. So `snork` is null.

Change your `onCreate` to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initialize();
    startLoop();
}
```

Comment: If you have called `initialize()` elsewhere, then perhaps the call to `Loader.loadMD2(res.openRawResource(R.raw.image), 0.5f)` is returning null, therefore giving `snork` a null value.

Comment: @Zéychin: I doubt it, it's an Android activity, and onCreate is just about the first thing the framework calls, after construction. You wouldn't have time to call initialize manually before onCreate is called.

Comment: See, I didn't realize that this was an Android activity; there's no Android tag and Android development is not my domain. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes I didn't retag it because it's not strictly related to Android, although that specific bit is :)

Answer (score 3):

Apparentlyy `snork` is null, which means that either `initialize()` does not run before `onCreate()` does, or the call to `Loader.loadMD2()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt intialize s2, when you check condition s2 value still not assigned.

```
if (i - s2 > rate) {
```

Comment: He has initialized in it Ticker constructor.